# bias ols estimator for a log-linear function

Tags: regression, econometrics, bias

If you originally thought that your log-linear OLS estimator was unbiased when infact it is biased what happens to the coefficients in the function.

As B1 is the proportional change in Ln(Y). Now that we know the function is bias would B1 decrease so the proportional change in Ln(y) decreases.

What would happen to Ln(Y)?